# How change function in Js from comma to dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function in JS which works fine with commas. I need to make it work with dot (ie. a number with a dot, not a comma). How can I change it? Replace in `indexOf(',')` to `indexOf('.')` has not helped me.

```js
$(".isInputNumber").on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ((event.which != 44 || $this.val().indexOf(',') != -1) 
    && ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) 
    && (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  var text = $(this).val();
  if ((event.which == 44) && (text.indexOf(',') == -1)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf(',')).length > 3) {
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf(',') + 3));
      }
    }, 1);
  }

  if ((text.indexOf(',') != -1) 
    && (text.substring(text.indexOf(',')).length > 2) 
    && (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) 
    && ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.which` property indicates the specific key or button that was pressed (44 code represents a comma). You should change that value to a dot code (i.e. 46) in accordance with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

Use `search` method, bacause it accepts regexp as an argument. And it will find first dot/comma.

In your case it will be like `search(/\.|,/)`. You can just replace your `indexOf` calls, because `search` also return an index of first match.

For example:

```
"123,123".search(/\.|,/) // return 3
"123.123".search(/\.|,/) // return 3 also
```